# Why database file is a yml instead of rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been asked in a recent interview why we make the database as a yml file instead of rb. Initially, I  was baffled by this question and I try to give an answer that we can serialize and deserialize the yml file but the answer was not satisfactory. So, can someone share his views over it

Comment: From a personal view 1. config in YAML separates code and configuration on functionality 2. YAML is easier to read with complex config without bothering about unrelated code part, bc it's focused on storing config information.

Comment: It's the same in reverse: think, why do you need to serialize data instead of writing them to code? Logically they should be separated and serialized plain text is easier to manage (no redundant irrelevant code in it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I noticed,

1. YAML is a superset of JSON. YAML is visually easier to look and easy to read.
2. We can use "anchors" to reference other data in YAML so it can handle relational data.
3. YAML is more robust about embedding other serialization formats such as JSON.
4. It will reduce unnecessary creation of objects like done in `.rb` file.

So storing configuration where only key-value pairs to be stored, are backed up by yaml files.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more  on anchors?

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari yes, refer [this](https://gist.github.com/bowsersenior/979804)

Answer (score 1):

In short, data and code should be separated for sanity. From a perspective of functionality, data plays a different role with code. That's why we store data in a database, or we serialized them to JSON and YAML.

Config from YAML is deserialization. It's human readable, free from bothering with irrelevant language concerns, and if you want to migrate from an old codebase, it's much easier when you have configurations in text format. YAML is over JSON here because of readability.

Rails is built on the concept of separating layers based on their logic functionality. Like, MVC is designed for the same reason. And you will have a separated auth layer out of the three if necessary.

Comment: The most common answer here seems to be separating out responsibility, but the MVC framework you mentioned does exactly that without enforcing another language.